# SQL Query using INTERVAL

Tags: mysql, sql

i am using this SQL Statement in PHP:

```
$sql2="SELECT * from billing_pdf_archive2 where datetime = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 14 DAY) and sequence = '".$result["sequence"]."' ";
```

its working fine however it is only selecting 14 days ago exactly from the datetime field. is there any way i can make it select 14 days ago and older? so 15, 16, 17, 18 days and so on.... but never less that 14 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than 14 days ago:

```
$sql2="SELECT * from billing_pdf_archive2 where datetime < DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 14 DAY) and sequence = '".$result["sequence"]."' ";
```